# Symfony change datetime field's format globally

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony-forms

I want to set date format to all datetime and date fields used in app globally. I thought I can achieve that using form theme, but when I tried to pass format variable in twig nothing happened.

```
    {{ form_row(form.date,{'format': 'dd.MM.yy'}) }}
```

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @DarkBee thanks for your answer but it's not duplicate. I want to change datetime form field's format. To override options added in FormType.

Comment: Have you tried the global config, like: `twig.date.format: dd.MM.yy`? (reference: https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/twig.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found solution, which was pretty simple. I used Symfony's extensions to override core built-in DateType, so I could set my desired date format.

```
final class DateTypeExtension extends AbstractTypeExtension
{
 /**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
 $resolver->setDefaults(array(
  'widget' => 'single_text',
  'format' => 'dd.MM.yyyy',
));
}
   /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getExtendedType()
 {
  return DateType::class;
  }
}
```